# Flutter program to share and print PDF from assets

Tags: pdf-viewer, flutter

I am looking for a flutter plugin that I can use with pdf in assets. I want to view, print, and share. Search within pdf would be awesome too, but lower on priority list. I am very new to programing/app development. Tried share_plus, share_extend, and printing, but having a hard time with the code.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Syncfusion Essential PDFViewer for Flutter](https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-pdf-viewer) is an option to consider.

[image: Flutter PDF Viewer]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: see also https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf and https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, syncFusion is very much what I was looking for an also easy to work with. Very helpful since I don't know what I'm doing (but working on it).
PDF viewer allows for file loading from local source, assets, and url. You can also use in-document word search and copy text functions.
Being small (only me) and no revenue from this project, the license was also free. Overall big win.
Thanks for the recommendation